# How to handle tables with twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to find my way using twitter-bootstrap, by reading the net and testing code on my own.

In order to get a mobile friendly display. Is it possible to have data displayed in rows of 6 items on a computer display and in rows of 3 items on a mobile? (A bit like an adjustable table)

Comment: Definitely not a answer to your question, but I've run across the same problem. I've been using [Bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/), which works like a charms. Instead of having multiple rows, this plugin creates a scrollable table. Maybe you'll find it usefull.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can use different columns sizes for every screen size.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2"> 1 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2"> 2 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2"> 3 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2"> 4 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2"> 5 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2"> 6 </div>
</div>
```

This gives you 3 columns on mobile and 6 in tablets and up.

For more info : http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: I must be doing something wrong (maybe some basic error), but when I try your code, I only get a vertical list from 1 to 6.

Comment: I am a total beginner using bootstrap.
Do you have a complete HTML page showing how your example works?

Comment: I finally found the solution, but how can I enforce spacing between rows?

Comment: You can create a new class with a margin-bottom or margin-top. Here you have an example: https://jsfiddle.net/9qnewwpo/3/

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I ended up by finding. I still have a few problem to solve before everything is perfect, but I am making progress.
My last question being http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531550/text-showing-up-vertically-with-bootstrap